# Using AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm try to use AutoResetEvent to pause the execution of the click event until the incoming event is fired but it is not working it only works after i do not need it anymore.

Here is the sample code for it

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ATModem
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public AutoResetEvent receiveNow = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>();

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            objclsSMS.incoming += objclsSMS_incoming;
        }

        void objclsSMS_incoming(string response)
        {
            log_events("Incoming Event: " + response);
            q.Enqueue(response);
            receiveNow.Set();
        }

        private void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            receiveNow.Reset();
            test.Enabled = false;
            test.Text = "Waiting...";

            if (receiveNow.WaitOne(5000)){
                while (q.Count != 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(q.Dequeue());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: \n" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                MessageBox.Show("Request Timed out");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly is going wrong.  Can you give us a bit more information?

Comment: You're waiting on UI thread it seems. It is a bad idea to do so. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve. May be there will be a better way to do.

Comment: `objclsSMS.incoming` event is being generated on ui thread?